# Leaflet Map lagging

Tags: performance, leaflet

I have got a Map using Leaflet which displays about 100,000 markers.
It works fine in Chrome.
It laggs badly in Firefox.
It doesn't work at all in IE.

What can I do to increase the performance?

Comment: You would probably be interested in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043791/plotting-140k-points-in-leafletjs/37044172#37044172

Answer (score 2):

Don't show all the markers at once. Use clustering or decluttering techniques, and consult the Leaflet plugins for doing just that.