# react-leaflet too many markers causes page to freeze

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, react-leaflet

I'm using react-leftlet to display markers in many counties. As you can see I'm mapping about 53K markers. The problem is that after I render these markers the webpage is practically unusable and it often freezes. Is there a way around this leaflet limitation? Is there a better way to display this many markers? Im using GeoJson as a data source. This is how I'm rendering these points:

```
<GeoJSON
   key={_.uniqueId()}
   data= {this.props.countrySelected.geojson}
   pointToLayer={this.pointToLayer.bind(this)}
></GeoJSON>
```

Here is the pointToLayer Function:

```
  pointToLayer = (feature, latlng) => {
// console.log(feature.properties);
return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
  color: this.getStyle(feature.properties.speed_connectivity, feature.properties.type_connectivity),
  fillColor: this.getStyle(feature.properties.speed_connectivity),
  fillOpacity: .6,
  radius: 1
}).bindPopup(popUpString(feature.properties)); // Change marker to circle
```

}

[image]

Update using heat map:

```
<HeatmapLayer
            fitBoundsOnLoad
            fitBoundsOnUpdate
            points={this.props.countrySelected.geojson}
            longitudeExtractor={m => m.geometry.coordinates[1]}
            latitudeExtractor={m => m.geometry.coordinates[1]}
            intensityExtractor={m => parseFloat(m.properties.speed_connectivity)}
          />
```

Comment: I do not exactly know react-leaflet, but if you can use the map `preferCanvas` option and display your points as Circle Markers, this should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015854/large-dataset-of-markers-or-dots-in-leaflet/43019740#43019740

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I am actually doing that. I have edited my post to reflect that. Take a look at the code above! Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, the performance is going to be terrible with that many markers.  I'd recommend using either [react-leaflet-markercluster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-markercluster) or [react-leaflet-heatmap-layer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer).

Comment: The issue is that heat map doesn't take geojson as data.

Comment: You can extract the lat/lon and intensity from the geojson using the react-leaflet-heatmap-layer api: https://github.com/OpenGov/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer#api.

Comment: How would I be a able to iterate through all points ? Right now I have what is above in the edit.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep points on the map you can use a WebGL canvas overlay, there's an example implementation of it [here](http://bl.ocks.org/Sumbera/c6fed35c377a46ff74c3)