# Trying to get faster leaflet mobile panning/zooming with about 1100 markers

Tags: javascript, leaflet

My goal is to make this map more mobile-friendly.  http://www.greenandtheblue.com/weather/milepost.html
One of the problems is that on a mobile device the panning and zooming is painfully slow, especially with poor connection.  I'm wondering if anyone has advice on how to speed this up?

I don't want to use clustering, and I don't know if the "canvas circles" option is possible because I want the text numbers to be displayed and not just a circle: [Large dataset of markers or dots in Leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015854/large-dataset-of-markers-or-dots-in-leaflet)

Are there any ideas on how to accomplish faster zooming/panning/performance with the 1100 markers I'm displaying?

Thanks for any help.

S