# Is there a way to implement canvas as renderer in Leaflet R instead of SVG?

Tags: r, leaflet

I need to plot >100k georreferenced points on a leaflet map I created with R. When plotting them with `addCircleMarkers` the map crashes on every browser.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015854/large-dataset-of-markers-or-dots-in-leaflet) it is suggested to replace SVG as the renderer so it doesn't create a DOM element for every data point, instead a Canvas layer. Nevertheless, I can't find the `preferCanvas` option in the `addCircleMarkers` function in R.

Does anyone know if this can be implemented in R?

Comment: Have you looked into `markerClusterOptions` in leaflet or `mapview` (also based on leaflet)?

Comment: Thanks MLavoie! Mapview apparently has a 'addLargeFeatures' function that does exactly that I think. I'll try it out and post back. Thanks again!

Comment: Check this post: https://community.rstudio.com/t/plotting-thousands-of-points-in-leaflet-a-way-to-improve-the-speed/8196/5