# R - Leaflet Limitations - How many markers does a leaflet map support?

Tags: r-leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

**Data**

I have a dataframe which contains 35,000 lat/lon locations. The locations have been plotted onto an interactive leaflet map.

**The Situation**

I would like to publish the map online via a markdown document.

**The Problem**

When I export the map as an html page or in markdown the map is:

- Laggy
- Hard to navigate
- Webpage Loads slowly

**Questions**

1. What is the maximum number of points you plot on a leaflet map without compromising the ability to navigate the map?
2. Would publishing the map as a shiny application help solve the loading speed, the maps lagginess and other performance issues?
3. If not, what other mapping programs integrate with R that yall would recommend?

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple options I can think that might help. The best would probably be to make clusters (see [Marker Clusters](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html#marker-clusters)):

```
addMarkers(..., clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
```

This prevents all 35 000 points from rendering at once which speeds up the loading time.

addCircles() and addCircleMarkers() seem to load quicker than addMarkers() as well if they're okay for your purposes although they're still slow with 35 000 points.

You could then do:

```
addCircleMarkers(..., clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
```

which should load even faster.

**Update**

Use leaflet.glify (`devtools::install_github("tim-salabim/leaflet.glify")`)

[Now leafgl (`devtools::install_github("r-spatial/leafgl")`) - see comment below.]

See [leaflet.glify](https://github.com/tim-salabim/leaflet.glify) [Now [leafgl](https://github.com/r-spatial/leafgl) - see comment below.]

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help! I tried that this morning but I think placing the dots into clusters minimizes the visual impact of the map. I found this example - http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html and it appears they have 30k datapoints. However the map functions much more fluid then my own and I cannot figure out why. Maybe my styling presets are too aggresive. Who knows.

Comment: Alright it looks like mapping points with leaflet is just slow. The author of that example just only posted 10,000 of the 30,000 plots. https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/master/063-superzip-example/server.R. Bummer I will look for another mapping tool unless there is another solution.

Comment: Okay, Good luck!

Comment: These might help. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227868/high-performance-markers-on-leaflet-map mentions a L_PREFER_CANVAS option that might be worth looking into otherwise this seems really promising https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015854/large-dataset-of-markers-or-dots-in-leaflet. Read through the answers and comments particularly this link https://github.com/tim-salabim/leaflet.glify

Comment: I have tested leaflet.glify and it works really well. The example uses 1 000 000 points

Comment: Thanks Eli! I will give that a try after work! That is exactly what I was looking for! In case someone else is looking for another solution I also found mapbox.

Comment: Sure, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Were you able to export the map? I am unable to export the map in markdown, or save it as an html page. For the purpose of mapping thousands of points it does indeed work! Thank you!

Comment: It seems not. I usually use shiny to publish apps and it doesn't seem to render these types of maps.

Comment: Bummer. Should i start looking for a 3rd party mapping platform/program to use? Is there another langauge such as python which might having a mapping tool that can better visualize the data? Other than using leaflet I do not have that much experience in mapping. Quite frankly, im surprised other people havent encountered this problem before -- and thank you for your help!

Comment: I am honestly out of my depth here. Maybe ask the developer of that package on GitHub?

Comment: Hi, leaflet.glify r package maintainer here. First of all note this package is now at r-spatial/leafgl. It now has dedicated shiny functions and should also work in rmarkdown documents. If you still have issues, please post an issue at the new githib location

Answer (score 1):

An approach I did use recently to plot more than 100k points and worked very well:

```
leaflet(options = leafletOptions(preferCanvas = TRUE))
```

This forces `leaflet` to render the map as canvas. More info [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/plotting-thousands-of-points-in-leaflet-a-way-to-improve-the-speed/8196/2).

The map appearance keep the same, but is much faster in terms of navigation. I didn't try `leaflet.glify` yet, but it seems to be a good solution to plot thousand points using `leaflet` package.