# how to pass icon to leaflet L.CircleMarker

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to use `L.CircleMarker` because performance was too bad for L.Marker, But I could pass my icon generated by `L.DivIcon` to `L.Marker` as an option so that markers would get painted like my passed icons.

Now, When I am using `L.CircleMarker`, I can't find anything which says how to pass custom icon to `L.CircleMarker`.

Does this mean I can't pass My custom icon to `L.CircleMarker`?

Comment: `L.CircleMarker` draws a circle. That's what it's for. If it helps, you can use `L.CircleMarker.setStyle()` to pass a custom `className` if you're using the SVG renderer.

Comment: I passed it, but I want to show image instead of circle, or background image . couldn't do it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56419682/5108796

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for **L.circleMarker** to load an icon directly.
I have been in similar situation and used a bit of hack combining **L.circle** and **L.marker**. I need to specify radius in meters didn't know how to convert it to pixels.
**L.circleMarker** allows to specify Radius of the circle marker, in pixels.
**L.circle** allows to specify Radius of the circle, in meters.

```
var map = L.map("map");
L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png").addTo(map);

map.setView([48.85, 2.35], 8);

var myRenderer = L.canvas({ padding: 0.5 });

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) { // 100 points getRandomLatLng();
var ltln = getRandomLatLng();
    L.circle(ltln, 5000,{
    renderer: myRenderer
  }).addTo(map).bindPopup('marker ' + i);
  L.marker(ltln).addTo(map).bindPopup('ICON ' + i);
}

function getRandomLatLng() {
    return [
    -90 + 180 * Math.random(),
    -180 + 360 * Math.random()
  ];
}
```

You can use customIcon with **L.marker**.
In my usecase, number of markers was low and hence no such performance degradation. **L.marker** has poorer performance for large number of points as compared to canvas based **L.circle**