# Is Leaflet capable of mapping +200,000 markers?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, coordinates, geocode

I'm trying to map around 226,000 markers for research purposes. Is this something viable with Leaflet? In the official documentation refers to 10,000 and 50,000 as "A LOT".

Comment: What's stopping you from testing it? And, more importantly, who should be deciding where exactly the line between *"acceptable"* and *"not acceptable"* should be drawn for your application?

Comment: Already tried it, below 50,000 works fine, but everytime I add more variables and call more files for reading the coordinates it just doesn't work... wondering if the task of mapping so much points is even a thing.

Comment: Well, I can tell you this much: you can't fit 226k markers on a screen. You should consider clustering and vector mapping. Clustering is the industry standard for this problem and it works remarkably well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015854/large-dataset-of-markers-or-dots-in-leaflet/43019740#43019740

this is what you need to do!

Comment: You may also take a look at [pixi overlay](https://github.com/manubb/Leaflet.PixiOverlay) as a tool to render this many markers through the use of canvas - its a nice solution as well.

Comment: Yes. I've already tried it with 1M points ( Total load time ~ 10 seconds, https://store.poidata.xyz/18660 )